# Non-resolvable parent POM for xxx

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I'm trying to package a maven project and the IDEA console says "Non-resolvable parent POM for xxx".
[image: console log]

The parent pom has been put in my maven local repository but can not be resolved by the submodules.

[image: parent pom directory]

[image: inside 1.0.0]

The submodule's pom.xml reports errors like this.

[image: submodule's error]

The parent pom.xml looks like this

```
<groupId>com.github.comctrl</groupId>
<artifactId>ComCtrl-Cloud</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<modules>
    <module>comctrl-auth</module>
    <module>comctrl-common</module>
    <module>comctrl-admin</module>
    <module>service-org</module>
    <module>service-administrative-division</module>
    <module>service-standard-address</module>
</modules>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<name>ComCtrl-Cloud</name>
```

The project seems like downloading the parent pom from the central repository and is not able to find it. It is supposed to resolve the pom.xml and download dependencies needed by submodules. I'm not sure what's going on. I'll be appreciated if anyone can help me!

Comment: You have configured a repository which does either not exist or does not contain the necessary artifacts. I strongly recommend to use the defaults and consume artifacts from central repository

Comment: @khmarbaise I've tried to include <relativePath> and it works fine. But I don't think this method addresses the problem properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't put the package on the right path, the right path should be ../local_repo/com/github/comctrl.